# How to make Hero animation for two widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to make animation like Hero in two different widgets. Is that possible?
Widget a with image a and widget b with image a but widget a is inside a listview and widget b is full screen image(it hide listview)

Comment: You post doesn't have enough information for anyone to help you. Please be more specific on what your issue is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: updated my question please check

Comment: When you say you want a Hero animation, does that mean you want an animation to happen between 2 Widgets in the same view that looks like the Hero animation. One widget moving and transforming to another Widget?

Comment: yes, right this is what i need

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You just need to wrap both widgets in a Hero widget using the same TAG property value. The snippet below is assuming you've a `Image` in a `ListTile` and after user clicks you show a new page with the same image but that image will be animated by `Hero` widget.

**In list page the list items can be**

```
ListTile(
      leading: Hero(
        tag: IMAGE_TAG, // must be the same in different pages
        child: Image(image: AssetImage('you_asset_dir/yourImage.png')),
      ),
      title: Text('Anything'),
      onTap: () => // Just go to full screen page
    );
```

**In full screen page**

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'IMAGE_TAG', // must be the SAME VALUE DEFINED IN list tile hero child widget.  
          child: Image(image: AssetImage('you_asset_dir/yourImage.png')),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

OBS: The `Hero` tag property must be the same in different contexts but if you have a list with many items using `Hero` widget each `Hero` int the same context/page must have different `tag` values.

To deep dive concepts about Hero animations check the [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)